# HttpresponseMessage risposta = await client.PostAsync(new Uri(uri), queryString); ends execution prematurely

Tags: c#, api, http, checkpoint

I'm trying to connect to CheckPoint APIs with some c# code, i type in all the data(username and password in json format and compile the Uri) and when i do the call it just ends the execution without exceptions

Here's the code

```
 public async Task<HttpResponseMessage> CPAPICall()
    {
        HttpClient client = new HttpClient();
        Console.Write("username: ");
        String uname = Console.ReadLine();
        Console.Write("password: ");
        String pwd = Console.ReadLine();
        String json = "{\n" +
                      "\"user\":" + "\"" + uname + "\",\n" +
                      "\"password\"" + "\"" + pwd + "\",\n" +
                      "}";
        StringContent queryString = new StringContent(json, Encoding.UTF8, "application/json");
        Console.WriteLine("Inserisci l'IP e la porta della management CP a cui vuoi connetterti (Esempio 192.168.1.1:443, se non si inserisce la porta quella di default è 443):");
        String IpAddr = Console.ReadLine();
        String[] IpAddrEPort = new String[2];
        HttpResponseMessage risposta = new HttpResponseMessage();
        if (IpAddr.Contains(":"))
        {
            IpAddrEPort = IpAddr.Split(':');
        }
        else
        {
            IpAddrEPort[0] = IpAddr;
            IpAddrEPort[1] = "443";
        }

        String uri = "https://" + IpAddr + "/web_api/login";
        try
        {
            risposta = await client.PostAsync(new Uri(uri), queryString);
        }
        catch (HttpListenerException e)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(e);
            Console.ReadKey();
        }
        String risp = risposta.StatusCode.ToString();
        Console.WriteLine(risp);
        Console.ReadKey();
        return risposta;
    }
```

json string management is pretty bad, but while i'm testing things it helps me.

code ends here `risposta = await client.PostAsync(new Uri(uri), queryString);`

Any suggestion on the cause?

Comment: When you say 'ends here' does the code throw any error / timeout? If not, I'm wondering if the API is doing something that awaits user feedback before returning. Such as a Google OAuth signing page or something.

Comment: It doesnt throw any error, CheckPoint APIs once the login process is acknowledged should return and acknowledgment with some data and the lines of code below should print this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would suggest using Newtonsoft.Json to serialize your strings data into a JSON correctly, it's 100% better. About the premature end, I think the method that is calling the 'CPAPICall' is not doing it in an asynchronous way, so check if this method was created asynchronously and have the await operator before the 'CPAPICall' on the same line.

Comment: i will give a try on the json advice, thanks.
I called ansynchronously the CPAPICall method after i found out that not doing that could case this issue, but with no luck(i'm still calling it async at the moment)

Comment: but did you include 'await' before the method call?

Comment: Yes i did it this way 

res = await CPAPICall();

and the method that's calling this is also called with await

Comment: Ok, i rebuilt the chain of async methods and await calls until the Main(). and now finally it gives me a connection error. thanks!